# Using set/list data types for intermediate keys in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

In an Apache Hadoop map-reduce program, what are the options for using sets/lists as keys in the output from the mapper?

My initial idea was to use `ArrayWritable` as key type, but that is not allowed, as the class does not implement `WritableComparable`. Do I need to define a custom class, or is there some other set like class in the Hadoop libraries that can act as key?

Comment: Can you give the use case where you be using list/set as keys in mapper

Comment: @PradyumnaMohapatra My question is more than four years old, but IIRC my intermediate key was a set of products bought together, with the intermediate values being ids of orders with this subset. The `reduce` method would then count the occurrence of each distinct set of products.

Answer (score 1):

I thought ArrayWritable implemented Writable which is a superinterface of WritableComparable.

Did you subclass ArrayWritable? According to the documentation you need to subclass it so that you can set the type of object to be stored by the array. For example:

```
public class TextArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable {

    public TextArrayWritable() {
        super(Text.class);
    }
}
```

Checkout the [ArrayWritable javadocs](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html).

Comment: `ArrayWritable` implements `Writable` but not `WritableComparable`, and apparently the latter is required for the class to be used for keys. I could subclass `ArrayWritable` and add support for the `WritableComparable` interface, but is this necessary?

Comment: Ah sorry looked a bit closer. The key needs WritableComparable because hadoop needs to be able to sort the keys. So, yes you could implement the WritableComparable interface which just requires you to override the compareTo method. Hope this helps.